# GMaps APIv3 InfoWindow for markers in loop for() is always the same

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, for-loop, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I know the topic has already been discussed many times, but I can't resolve my problem.
I'd like to display some markers on my map, with a click event on each of them. Each click event should open an infoWindow with some data.

Here is what I wrote ; this code runs without any error in the console, all the markers are correctly displayed, but the infowindow displayed on click is always the same for all...

```
//Global variable
var info = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

//... some other functions

function createMarker(map)
{
    for(i = 0 ; i < loadedMarkers.length ; i++) { 
        (function(i) {
            value = loadedMarkers[i];
            var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(value.Latitude, value.Longitude);

            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 10,
                center: pos,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: pos,
                map: map,
                title: value.Title
            });

            var MarkerContent = "<div class=\"marker\">" +
                                    "<h2>"+ value.Title +"</h2>" +
                                    "<p>"+ value.Text +"</p>" +
                                "</div>";

            info.setOptions({
                content: MarkerContent,
                size: new google.maps.Size(50, 50),
                position: pos
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                info.open(map, marker);
            }); 
         }
       )(i);
    }
}
```

I heard about some closure problem (I'm new with JS), so I tried to put the logic in the (function(i) ...), but it always display the same content for all infowindow.

Could someone explain me where I'm wrong (and why ?)

Thanks you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update the content in the infowindow when it is opened (otherwise it displays the last content):

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        info.setOptions({
            content: MarkerContent
        });
        info.open(map, marker);
    });
```

Comment: Perfectly working thank you so much !! But I still don't understand why, in my previous code, the content of the infowindow wasn't updated each round of the loop...

Comment: It was (MarkerContent was updated and set as the content of the one and only infowindow).  But the last value set was used in the click listener since you weren't updating it with the value specific to the marker clicked when the click listener ran.